# How to bounce a QWidget around the desktop

Tags: c++, qt6

I am trying to bounce a QWidget around the screen.  This is the code i tried.

```
class Window : public QMainWindow {
  public:
    void moveEvent(QMoveEvent* aEvent) override;
};

void Window::moveEvent(QMoveEvent* aEvent) {
  QSizeF screenSize = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->screenSize();
  QRect oldRect = this->geometry();
  QRect newRect = oldRect;
  QPoint offset;

  if (newRect.left() == 0) {
    offset.setX(1);
  }
  else if (newRect.right() == screenSize.width()) {
    offset.setX(-1);
  }
  if (newRect.top() == 0) {
    offset.setX(1);
  }
  else if (newRect.bottom() == screenSize.height()) {
    offset.setX(-1);
  }
  newRect.setTopLeft(newRect.topLeft() + offset);
  newRect.setBottomRight(newRect.bottomRight() + offset);

  QTimer::singleShot(1, [this, newRect]() {
    setGeometry(newRect);
  });
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  QApplication app{argc, argv};

  Window* w = new Window();
  w->show();
  w->setGeometry(w->geometry());

  return app.exec();
}
```

However, the window does not move around the screen, but somewhat jitters in place.  When i move the window with the mouse and let go.  It moves sporadically around the desktop, which is also not what i want.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  If so, does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the posted code, including:

- The `Window` class doesn't have any member-variable to keep track of its current direction of motion.  Without keeping that state, it's impossible to correctly calculate the next position along that direction of motion.
- Driving the animation from within `moveEvent()` is a bit tricky, since `moveEvent()` gets called in response to `setGeometry()` as well as in response to the user actually moving the window with the mouse; that makes unexpected feedback loops possible, resulting in unexpected behavior.
- The code assumes that the screen's usable surface area starts at `(0,0)` and ends at `(screenSize.width(),screenSize.height())`, which isn't necessarily a valid assumption.  The actual usable area of the screen is a rectangle given by `availableGeometry()`.
- When calling `setGeometry()`, you are setting the new location of the area of the window that the Qt program can actually draw into.  However that's only a 99% subset of the actual on-screen area taken up by the window, because the window also includes the non-Qt-controlled regions like the title bar and the window-borders.  Those parts need to fit into the `availableGeometry()` also, otherwise the window won't be positioned quite where you wanted it to be, which can lead to anomalies (like the window getting "stuck" on the top-edge of the screen)

In any case, here's my attempt at rewriting the code to implement a closer-to-correct "bouncing window".  Note that it's still a bit glitchy if you try to mouse-drag the window around while the window is also trying to move itself around; ideally the Qt program could detect the mouse-down-event on the title bar and use that to disable its self-animation until after the corresponding mouse-up-event occurs, but AFAICT that isn't possible without resorting to OS-specific hackery, because the window-title-bar-dragging is handled by the OS, not by Qt.  Therefore, I'm leaving that logic unimplemented here.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMoveEvent>
#include <QShowEvent>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QTimer>

class Window : public QMainWindow {
public:
    Window() : pixelsPerStep(5), moveDelta(pixelsPerStep, pixelsPerStep)
    {
       updatePosition();  // this will get the QTimer-loop started
    }

private:
    void updatePosition()
    {
       const QRect windowFrameRect = frameGeometry();  // our on-screen area including window manager's decorations
       const QRect windowRect      = geometry();       // our on-screen area including ONLY the Qt-drawable sub-area

       // Since setGeometry() sets the area not including the window manager's window-decorations, it
       // can end up trying to set the window (including the window-decorations) slightly "out of bounds",
       // causing the window to "stick to the top of the screen".  To avoid that, we'll adjust (screenRect)
       // to be slightly smaller than it really is.
       QRect screenRect = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->availableGeometry();
       screenRect.setTop(    screenRect.top()    + windowRect.top()    - windowFrameRect.top());
       screenRect.setBottom( screenRect.bottom() + windowRect.bottom() - windowFrameRect.bottom());
       screenRect.setLeft(   screenRect.left()   + windowRect.left()   - windowFrameRect.left());
       screenRect.setRight(  screenRect.right()  + windowRect.right()  - windowFrameRect.right());

       // Calculate where our window should be positioned next, assuming it continues in a straight line
       QRect nextRect = geometry().translated(moveDelta);

       // If the window is going to be "off the edge", set it to be exactly on the edge, and reverse our direction
       if (nextRect.left()   <= screenRect.left())    {nextRect.moveLeft(  screenRect.left());   moveDelta.setX( pixelsPerStep);}
       if (nextRect.right()  >= screenRect.right())   {nextRect.moveRight( screenRect.right());  moveDelta.setX(-pixelsPerStep);}
       if (nextRect.top()    <= screenRect.top())     {nextRect.moveTop(   screenRect.top());    moveDelta.setY( pixelsPerStep);}
       if (nextRect.bottom() >= screenRect.bottom())  {nextRect.moveBottom(screenRect.bottom()); moveDelta.setY(-pixelsPerStep);}
       setGeometry(nextRect);

       QTimer::singleShot(20, [this]() {updatePosition();});
    }

    const int pixelsPerStep;
    QPoint moveDelta;  // our current positional-offset-per-step in both X and Y direction
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  QApplication app{argc, argv};

  Window* w = new Window();
  w->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```